# PHP logout link wrong

Tags: php, html, session, hyperlink, path

I have an icon for log out. The Problem is, when i click on the logout icon it logs me out but the design of my logout form looks different and the link is also wrong instead of index.html it links me to logout.php just after refreshing I am on the right path.

What could be my problem?

Thats on a html page, I set the link to logout.php

```
<li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
```

[index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkaoX.png)

Thats my logout.php code

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

[logout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKHk3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax mistake

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php"
?>
```

Missing closing brackets and also maybe you need to change redirection to index.html

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php"); // here maybe index.html depending where do you want to redirect 
?>
```

Comment: ohh sorry my mistake I just forget the brackets here but in the original there are closing brackets. okay i will try to redirect it to index.html

Comment: No, the problem still exists after changing the redirection

Comment: So wait after it logs you out it do not redirect you to index page?

Comment: Yes, it just redirects me to logout.php instead of index.php

Comment: Look when you click on `<li><a href="logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>` it is okay to redirect you to logout.php page and then this part `header("Location: index.php");` should return you to index page. Be aware that index.php or index.html must exist. It can not redirect you to not existing page so pls check one more time of the name of page where you want header to return you.

Comment: Also check directory where this file is located so you must add path to header if index and logout.php files are not on the same place

Comment: I load up a picture maybe that explains better what I mean. And yes the index.php exists

Comment: Did you try to redirect to login page instead of index.php?

Comment: but my login page is my index

Comment: Okay. Is this only content on logout.php or there is more code. did you try to change index.php with for example www.google.com just to see if it execute header command

Comment: Thats the only content, it's just a login form. I load this on a webserver and the same problem exists there. The redirections are right. And I also debugged it but the debugger show's no mistakes.

Comment: hmm strange why is not redirecting you